# iPhone uisegmentcontrol views overlap

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

I hava a view with UISegmentControl 'SegA','SegB' and 'SegC'

Each Segments has different view with labels and textfields which was added programmatically.

Whenever i switch from SegA to SegB, view of SegA overlaps on view of SegB

Answer (score 0):

for example You have 3 views with respective 3 segment controls, You need to add those views on main view Controller as subviews and also set the frame for them through code or add them on ViewController using Interface Builder.

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.view addSubView:view1];
[self.view addSubView:view2];
[self.view addSubView:view3];

[view1 setHidden:NO];
[view2 setHidden:YES];
[view3 setHidden:YES];

[mySegmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(valuedChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 }   

//segment value changed
-(IBAction)valuedChanged:(id)sender{

UISegmentedControl* tempSC=(UISegmentedControl *)sender;
if(tempSC.selectedSegmentIndex==0){
[view1 setHidden:NO];
[view2 setHidden:YES];
[view3 setHidden:YES];
}
else if(tempSC.selectedSegmentIndex==1){
[view1 setHidden:YES];
[view2 setHidden:NO];
[view3 setHidden:YES];
}
else if(tempSC.selectedSegmentIndex==2){
[view1 setHidden:YES];
[view2 setHidden:YES];
[view3 setHidden:NO];
}
}
```

provided view1, view2 and view3 are the instance of the UIView Class.